# MSBuild task fails to copy on VSTS Agent build

Tags: xamarin.forms, realm, azure-pipelines

After switching to Realm and adding it to my solution, my VSTS build for my xamarin.forms application fails to run.

The error message i get:
"Unable to copy file "RealmWeaver.Fody.dll" to "*Undefined*Tools\RealmWeaver.Fody.dll". Illegal characters in path.

A google search led me to a blogpost that show that VSTS changes the value of SolutionDir to undefined. The workaround to pass an additional argument
"/p:SolutionDir=”/”" to MSBuild doesn't work though.

Comment: What if you change `SolutionDir` in your project as Rabi mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by adding SolutionDir to each project file using Realm and Fody.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <SolutionDir>..\</SolutionDir>
</PropertyGroup>
```